# How to use logical operators on input function within an if statement in python 3.7?

Tags: python, input

I'm still in the early stages of learning python so this is probably an easy question that I just can't find the answer for. I'm trying to take user input to define 2 variables and compare them using > and < in an if statement.

line 6-11 in the code below I've also tried ...is False: and also y > x is True

```
print("what is x")
x = int(input('> ))
print("what is y")
y = int(input('> ))

if x > y is True:
    print("x > y")
elif x > y is not True:
    print("y > x")
else:
    print("whatever")
```

If x > y then it says y > x.
If y > x, it prints the else condition.

Comment: You don't need (or want) the explicit comparison to Boolean. Just do `if x > y:`.

Comment: Just for the heck of it:
`print(["x < y", "whatever", "x > y"][(x > y) - (x < y) + 1])`

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets around your x/y comparison.  I modified the code and I think it works as you intended now:

```
print("what is x")
x = int(input('> '))
print("what is y")
y = int(input('> '))
if (x > y) is True:
    print("x > y")
elif (x > y) is not True:
    print("y > x")
else:
    print("whatever")
```

EDIT: As others have pointed out in the comments, you don't have to explicitly compare the result of `x > y`.  You can just do this:

```
print("what is x")
x = int(input('> '))
print("what is y")
y = int(input('> '))
if x > y
    print("x > y")
elif y > x:
    print("y > x")
else:
    print("whatever")
```

Comment: I knew it was something dumb like that. It works now, thanks!

Comment: The parens in `if (x > y)` and are useless in your second example.

Comment: You're right @Jean-ClaudeArbaut.  I've removed them from the example. They were just left over from copy-pasting the code from above.